# Swift tuple behaves correctly in Xcode 6 but not on the command line

Tags: swift, xcode6

```
let foo = { () -> (foo:Int, bar:Int) in return (1, 2) }()
```

In Xcode 6 playground, `foo.bar` returns 2. However, on `swift` command line* it returns:

```
<REPL>:28:1: error: 'Int' does not have a member named 'bar'
foo.bar
^   ~~~
```

*/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

Comment: I have no such problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I thought you might have assigned the closure to `foo` instead of the result from actually calling it.

But, from reading your error message, it actually seems you've assigned an `Int` value to `foo` prior to making the `foo.bar` call.

The only situation I can imagine would cause this behaviour is if you had priorly declared `foo` with an int value and then tried to redefine it assigning the closure. While the REPL would seem to redefine foo, it would not, and no warning or error would be issued. See below:

[image: Redefining foo]

---

**Starting a new REPL and making sure that didn't happen, it seems to work fine.**

[image: REPL Output]

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the problem. In addition to your comments, I found that setting via `var` has the same issue. This tells me that once type is inferred for any variable/constant, it can't be changed later.